# Add Expires Headers for Specific Images

Tags: .htaccess, mod-expires

All of the expires headers articles I've looked at give more or less the following solution:

```
ExpiresByType image/gif A2592000
ExpiresByType image/png A2592000
ExpiresByType image/jpg A2592000
ExpiresByType image/jpeg A2592000
```

But it doesn't make sense to me because I know which of my images are going to change and which aren't, so I want to be able to add specific expiration dates to specific image files. How would I go about this?

Answer (score 10):

You can use a `FilesMatch`, eg.

```
<FilesMatch "\.(js|css)$">
  ExpiresActive on 
  ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
</FilesMatch>
```

Or for some specific files:

```
<FilesMatch "^(example.js|sample.css)$">
  ExpiresActive on 
  ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Could you give an example of how to apply this to a specific image file: example.jpg ?  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your help ar, much appreciated: So would the following work?

(image.jpg|anotherImage.png|backgroundImage.png|bannerImg.jpg)

Comment: Adding this code to my .htaccess gave me a 500 internal server error.

Comment: @a'r: I think you need to escape the dot `<FilesMatch "^(example\.js|sample\.css)$">` and it might be worth adding also `Header append Cache-Control "public"` read more: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10034368/260080

Answer (score 3):

Note that using `ExpiresDefault` for specific files will not work if you already used `ExpiresByType`. You need to use `ExpiresByType` again.

So this will NOT work (`service-worker.js` would still have +1 year expiry):

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive on
    ExpiresDefault                                      "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript                "access plus 1 year"
    <FilesMatch "^(service-worker.js)$">
        ExpiresDefault                                  "access plus 0 seconds"
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

But this will work (`service-worker.js` will have +0 seconds expiry):

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive on
    ExpiresDefault                                      "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript                "access plus 1 year"
    <FilesMatch "^(service-worker.js)$">
        ExpiresByType application/javascript            "access plus 0 seconds"
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

You might also use `Header unset Expires`. This would remove `Expires` header no matter what was set above it. You should also modify (or remove) `Cache-Control` header. It seems that `mod_expires` sets both.

```
    <FilesMatch "^(service-worker.js)$">
        Header unset Expires
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0"
    </FilesMatch>
```