# .htaccess expires headers for specific file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http-headers, mime-types, mod-expires

I have been setting up general cache durations using ExpiresByType and mime types in an .htaccess file.

However, I have some individual files that I would like to specify different (much longer) cache durations to the generic setting for that mime type. Is there a way to apply cache durations a specific named files?

Comment: Check this link: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#files You can use that or `FilesMatch` directives and put the differing options in there

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add Expires Headers for Specific Images](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2508783/add-expires-headers-for-specific-images)