# Cache expires not applying to some images in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, caching

I defined cache expires for my Wordpress but SpeedTest still tells me I should fix it for some jpg and png images.

I have [Cache Enabler](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cache-enabler/) plugin installed and added the following to my .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive On
  ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 604800 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 600 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/xhtml+xml "access plus 600 seconds"
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
 <filesMatch ".(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|svg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
 Header set Cache-Control "max-age=84600, public"
 </filesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\\.(css)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2692000, public"
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\\.(js)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=216000, private"
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\\.(x?html?|php)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=600, private, must-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>

Header unset ETag
Header unset Last-Modified

</IfModule>
```

I also tried to follow [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2508783/add-expires-headers-for-specific-images) but still no luck.

Is there a particular reason why these images won't have their cache expiration defined?

All images are on my server by the way, most of them on the folders:

wp-content/uploads/cache/

wp-content/themes/Wordpress/images/