# Dynamic Image Caching

Tags: optimization, caching, apache2, cherrypy, memoization

I have a CherryPy app that dynamically generates images, and those images are re-used a lot but generated each time. The image is generated from a querystring containing the variables, so the same query string will always return the same image (until I rewrite the generation code) and the images are not user-specific.

It occurred to me that I should be aggressively caching those images, but I have no idea how I would go about doing that. Should I be memoizing in CherryPy? Should I do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/447014) for Apache? Another layer entirely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first attempt should be to use the HTTP cache that comes with CherryPy. See http://docs.cherrypy.org/dev/refman/lib/caching.html for an overview. From there, it's usually a "simple" matter  of balancing computational expense versus RAM consumption via cache timeouts.