# Current filetypes which are cached by current browsers

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, browser, browser-cache

I am developing a website which is extensively using jquery dom javascript ajax etc. I am dividing the javascript files to be cached and it saves me around 0.2 seconds, also, I have templates on the main page, which are hidden and I switch between hidden and visible, when I want to use these elements on the page, (like div or table, some elements which are selected and inserted into another content div", but I want to load these static templates from a file, so that the browser gets the file, and on page refreshes, the browser laods the static html file from cache, and It will save me a lot of miliseconds this way. but I don't know if current browsers assume htm files are static. I am helping the browser to assume the file is static, by saving it as *.htm , instead of *.php. What file extensions should I use, for making the browser assume they are static files? would htm be assumed to be static? Would you suggest using *.txt?

Comment: Ooh, milliseconds... I can totally tell the difference when a page takes *a few milliseconds* longer to load...

Comment: @Kolink my competitive advantage against the rival site is speed. I would like to listen if you have any ideas about browser caching.

Comment: If speed is the only advantage you have... perhaps you should try to have content that people are willing to wait a fraction of a second longer for?

Comment: @Kolink maybe dial down the snark a little?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to set the correct HTTP caching headers on your files when you serve them.

https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/caching

For static files you can configure your webserver to do this (eg [Website image caching with Apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/447014/website-image-caching-with-apache)), for dynamic files you can do this on the fly (in PHP with the [`header()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function).

Note that the file extension doesn't really matter either, you should tell the browser what the type of files is using the `Content-Type` header (though the extension will help your webserver guess this).