# Tooltip update sending multiple requests

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I am using Extjs 4.0.7.

The tooltip(Ext.tip.Tooltip) to show some message is coming correctly. When I check in the network tab of the browsers development tools, it is sending multiple requests. But I want a single request to be sent.

```
couponTpl: function (value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store, view) {
    view.tip = Ext.create('Ext.tip.ToolTip', {
        target: view.el,
        delegate: view.itemSelector,
        anchor: 'left',
        trackMouse: true,
        dismissDelay: 100,
        scope: this,
        showDelay: 300,
        height: 300,
        hideDelay: 0,
        listeners: {
            beforeshow: function updateTipBody(tip) {
                var record = view.getRecord(tip.triggerElement);
                tip.update('<div><span> record.data.offer</span></div>');
            }
        }
    });
    return value;
}
```

[image: checkdis]

Comment: Your code isn't sending off a network request at all there.

Comment: i checked in the network . many request are going to server

Answer (score 0):

You should enable a caching mechanism on the server side.

`record.data.offer` contains image tags. Default behavior is that the image will automatically be loaded. But if you enable a caching mechanism this will be resolved by the browser.

One of these mechanisms is to let the server set an expiration date. A period in which the content is valid/up-to-date.

Then the browser checks internally if the content has expired it fetches the image again. Else it's coming from the cache. Here is an [example using apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/447014/website-image-caching-with-apache)

Another (more advanced/complex) mechanism is using [eTags](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag)

Comment: <img src="' + record.data.imagePath +
                            '" alt=" Image not found "' + ' width="150" > is using to display image can you please explain me in detail about caching machanism

Comment: Like I said. It contains 1 or more `img` tags. This isn't an ExtJs issue but default browser behavior.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply , can you please explain me how to resolve it indetail

Comment: @Satish Did you look at the example? It should be sufficient.