# Advice on mimetypes to include in Apache mod_expires

Tags: javascript, html, apache, mod-expires

I used this excellent post [Website image caching with Apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/447014/website-image-caching-with-apache) to define my header expires. And I have looked at numerous other examples, and they all pretty much outline the same; enable for images and css, disable for php, python etc.

**But I am a bit ambiguous about JavaScripts and HTML. Can I add header expire for those as well? Without compromising the live content of the site? I am running Simple Machines forum.**

By top eight mimetypes by use look like this, so there is something to gain:

```
php  46.5 %
png  22.9 %
js   6.5 %
html 5.9 %
gif  5.8 %
css  4.8 %
jpg  4.7 %
jpeg 2.6 %
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I dug around the Simple Machines forums and was recommended to enable it for JavaScript but not for HTML as the *pretty URL* function makes some dynamic pages apear as HTML, e.g. `index.php/board,1.0.html`

Have been testing it for a couple of days now and found no issues so far, and it has really reduced the daily download.