# HTML Cache one image only

Tags: html, image, caching

I have a site with multiple page. Each page has a background image I'd like to cache so it's not reloaded between pages.

I don't want to cache anything else.. only this one image.

How do I do that ?
Can someone point me in the right direction.

Thanks

Comment: You can solve this with Jquery/javascript http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10240110/how-do-you-cache-an-image-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that in apache2 configuration.
Here are some of ways to do that

1. Using htaccess and mod_expire. Please see  [Details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/447014/website-image-caching-with-apache)
2. Using mod_disk_cache reference here [apache mod_disk_cache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_disk_cache.html)

Comment: Thanks that looks like what I need :)